# Given some information of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $f$, show that $f(x)+x^{\beta}\longrightarrow\infty$ if and only if $\beta>\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers, limsup-and-liminf

The reason of this post was another post I saw this afternoon. However, I cannot find the post anymore, so I am not able to provide the link.

The OP was about this: he knows about $$\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{2x\log\log x}}=1\ \text{and}\ \liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{2x\log\log x}}=-1.$$

Then, he wants to show $f(x)+x^{\alpha}\longrightarrow\infty$ if and only if $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.

There was no answer but only some comments in that post. Among comments, one suggested using the fact that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\log x}{x^{r}}=\infty,\ \text{for all}\ r>0,$$ so that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(x^{r}-\sqrt{2\log\log x})=\infty\ \text{for all}\ r>0.$$

Then, using the condition of $\liminf$, writing out as $$f(x)+x^{\alpha}>x^{\alpha}+(-1-\epsilon)\sqrt{2x\log\log x},$$ it is fairly easy to prove the direction $(\Leftarrow)$.(Factor out $x^{1/2}$ and replace $r:=\alpha-\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I could not figure out $(\Rightarrow)$. Even though $r\leq 0$ implies $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(x^{r}-\sqrt{2\log\log x})=-\infty,$$ we cannot use it, since if we apply the similar argument, we would arrive at $$\liminf f(x)+x^{\alpha}>-\infty,$$ which is not useful at all.

Then, I tried to use the condition on $\limsup$, but that only gives $\limsup f(x)+x^{\alpha}<\infty$, which is not useful either..

What should I do? thank you!

Comment: @saz yes. just edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the case $\alpha=1/2$.

Since $$\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{2x \log \log x}} = - 1,$$

there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and

$$ \frac{f(x_n)}{\sqrt{2x_n\log \log x_n}} \leq -\frac{1}{2} .$$

Thus,

\begin{align*} f(x_n) + \sqrt{x_n} &= \sqrt{x_n} \left( \frac{f(x_n)}{\sqrt{x_n}}+1 \right) \\ &\leq \sqrt{x_n} \left( - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 \log \log x_n} + 1 \right). \end{align*}

Since $\sqrt{x_n} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 \log \log x_n} + 1 \right) = - \infty,$$

it follows that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) + \sqrt{x_n} = - \infty.$$ (Note: If $(a_n)_n$, $(b_n)_n$ are real-valued sequences such that $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to - \infty$, then $a_n b_n \to -\infty$.) Hence, $$\liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) + \sqrt{x} = - \infty.$$

If $\alpha < 1/2$, then $x^{\alpha} < \sqrt{x}$ for $x \geq 1$, and hence,

$$\liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) + x^{\alpha} \leq \liminf_{x \to \infty} f(x) + \sqrt{x} = -\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the problem is I don't think by proving $\liminf\leq-\infty$ implies $\lim=-\infty$. Since we don't know what happens to the $\limsup$

Comment: oh so you showed $\alpha\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\implies \liminf=-\infty$, and thus $\liminf>\infty$ is not true, so $\alpha\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$ does not imply $\lim=\infty$? this is like, to prove $1\implies 2$ we show not $2$ implies not $1$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Since the limes inferior is $-\infty$, the limit cannot be equal to $+\infty$ (because then also the limes inferior would be $+\infty$).

Comment: got you. Thank you so much!